# How to add credential for `docker exec` command

Tags: docker

I have created a docker container from `ubuntu` image. Other users can attach to this container by `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash`. Is there a way to add username and password for this command? I don't want my container to be accessed by other users. I want when users execute `docker exec` command to attach to my container, it prompts to ask a username and password. Users can only attach to it after input a correct username and password. Just like what ssh does.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry i didn't make it clear. I have updated my post and I want the `docker exec` command prompts a username and password. Just like `ssh` or `telnet` command.

Comment: Docker exec is very different to SSH - you're not opening a shell, you're literally just executing an arbitrary process.  It sounds like you shouldn't be letting other users touch your container in the first place.

Comment: Right, how can I stop users connect to my container through `docker exec` command?

Comment: I assume it is possible to set up policykit rules for this. If other users don't have root password and aren't member of group docker, you can allow them `docker run` and `docker exec` with different polices. Though, I am not familar with details of such a setup. `pkexec docker exec` could be configured to ask for authentication.

Comment: It's 2020 and still no solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Access to the docker socket (which is used by the docker command line), should be treated as sysadmin level access to the host and all containers being run on that host.

You can configure the docker daemon to listen on a port with TLS credentials and validation of client certificates. However, once a user has access to any docker API calls, they would have access to them all, and without any login prompts.

You could try a third party plugin provided by Twistlock that implements the authz plugin for docker. This will let you limit access to the exec call to specific TLS client certificates. However it will not limit which containers they can exec into.

Probably the closest to what you want comes with Docker's EE offering, specifically UCP. It's a commercial tool, but they provide a different API entrypoint that performs its own authentication, including the option for a user/password with web based requests, and RBAC security that lets you limit access to calls like `exec` to specific users and specific collections of containers.

If you wanted to do this from the container side, I'm afraid that won't work. Exec is run as a Linux exec syscall directly inside the container namespace, so there's nothing inside the container you could do to prevent that sort of access. The best option is to remove any commands from your image that you don't want anyone to be able to run in the container.